# What is the correct sequence of including jquery files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

Today i wanted to add datepicker() to my page.So I downloaded jqueryui and added then in the sequence below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/retina.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/validate.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
<script src="js/wizard_func.js"></script>
<script src="check_radio/jquery.icheck.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/navi_artstyle.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapmarker.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapmarker_func.jquery.js"></script>
```

It didn't work. It took me whole day to figure out what is wrong. it was the SEQUENCE of js files included!!! To work my code i had to include them like bellow.("`jquery.js`" position had to change)

```
    <script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/retina.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/validate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.placeholder.js"></script>
    <script src="js/functions.js"></script>
    <script src="js/wizard_func.js"></script>
    <script src="check_radio/jquery.icheck.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navi_artstyle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapmarker.jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mapmarker_func.jquery.js"></script>
```

Can some one explain this please. Please give me a Source so I wont make this mistake again.

Comment: It's quite easy, add files as they are required, as in anything that requires jQuery goes after jQuery, anything that depends on jQuery UI goes after jQuery UI etc.

Comment: Always jquery library be top of all scripts

Comment: There is no single correct answer here. It will entirely depend on what script you include, and what dependencies they have. `jquery.js` should nearly always come first though.

Comment: Add and configure RequireJS to your project and let it handle the loading of scripts.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that is what i thought before this happen. but according to this case if I add jquery.js First it dosen't work. anyways thanx for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Normal jQuery (core)
2. jQuery migrate if you have
3. jQuery UI
4. jQuery mobile
5. Scripts that need jQuery / scripts that are jQuery plugins
6. Other scripts like bootstrap
7. You own scripts depending which is needed first

Answer (score 0):

First you have to include normal jQuery library.After that You have to include other jquery library like jquery ui and jquery mobile and all finally you have to include your own javascript files.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments you have to mention the scripts in the order you use that.

Simply anything used Jquery will goes after jQuery, anything that depends on jQuery UI goes after jQuery UI etc.